# WebView not displaying correctly using javascript getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have my WebView displaying the webpage for my Android application, but I don't want the header with the website title and ad to display. This is the code that I have written and I'm not sure why it is not removing the header in my WebView.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('logo-wrapper colored-header').style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
        }

    });
    String url = "http://davisclipper.com";



    WebSettings.ZoomDensity zoomDensity = WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR;
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(zoomDensity);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Maybe there is something obvious that I'm doing wrong, but I'm wasting a lot of time trying to find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're confident your JavaScript is executing on the page, you may just have a tiny error in your JavaScript code. That's why it appears to be doing nothing.

I believe `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not just a single element. I don't think you can set `style` on that. Instead, you can grab the first element in the `HTMLCollection` and go from there.

Try something like this. It should work if you're only trying to hide only one element with those classes.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('logo-wrapper colored-header')[0].style.display='none'
```

If you end up needing to hide more than one element with those classes, you can try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('logo-wrapper colored-header').map(el => { el.style.display = 'none' })
```